# Does Arduino ADK shield for android, serves like a regular USB host shield?

Tags: arduino, usb-host

I'm from Argentina and the guy whom I bought the Arduino accesories from doesn't have any USB hosts. But he has [this](http://www.argeduino.com.ar/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=101).

I'm not interested in connecting an Android phone to it but I certainly would in the future. Right now I'm only interested in connecting a DSRL camera and a Joystick with USB.

In [this article here](http://emartee.com/product/42089/Arduino%20ADK%20Shield%20For%20Android), it says "Support USB HOST mode，support HUB protocol".

Just to be sure, does it have the very same functionality as a regular USB host shield?

Comment: $226.00?? For that same shield they sell [here](http://emartee.com/product/42089/Arduino%20ADK%20Shield%20For%20Android) for 36 dollar?

Comment: Argentine pesos use the same symbol ($) as USD: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=argentina+%24226.00

Comment: It's equivalent to 50 dollar with  official rate or 34 dollar if you change the money in the black market!

Comment: Oh, the ambiguity!! :-(

Comment: Darn, Wolfram|Alpha can't do that one: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%24226.00+Argentine+pesos+in+USD+with+black+market+conversion

Comment: Some things are beyond math and computation... Argentina is one of those things!!

Comment: @SimpleCoder - Do you use Alpha for mathematics also? I read on mathematica.stackexchange.com that it would have some bugs. Ever noticed anything like that? (I don't know why Alpha doesn't use the Mathematica engine.)

Comment: I think it does... I have Mathematica installed, but use wolfram alpha a lot, the syntax is the same, and wolfram is more flexible (at least for simple operations). By the way, on this spontaneous and miscellaneous forum any ideas regarding the purchase of the USB shield!! haha...

Comment: @limoragni - Sorry, I've got no answer for the shield. About Alpha. I presumed it uses the MMA engine, but for several valid expressions I tried it said it didn't understand. And already after a few tries I found the first bug: `Solve[a(-Log[0.7] - Log[0.3]) == 1*^-6, a]` says "no solution exists", while MMA gives the correct solution: 6.4076*10^-7.

Comment: @stevenvh: Sorry, didn't see your comment till now. For some reason the system isn't notifying me when people tag me. I do use Alpha a good bit, with two primary use cases. 1) When I'm feeling lazy and I just want a quick result to a question I have, Alpha is pretty good at parsing natural language, so I can usually directly type my question (about almost anything) and get an answer. 2) It's also a great way to check my work, for example, to check that I've simplified something correctly. Check out the [Examples page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/). It's quite exhaustive.

Comment: Also, I think the solution MMA gave you is wrong. Try evaluating it in Alpha: http://bit.ly/NyV0P9 - click "More digits" next to the result, and you'll see that what MMA gave you is not actually an exact solution. So I think Alpha is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, despite the abscense of an answer I've just purchase the ADK USB host shield and try it's functionality as a regular USB host with great results, at least on the project in which I'm working ...

What I really like about it, is that it can also be used with android, so if you are thinking in buying an USB host I think this is the way to go!

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is useful information for other Arduino experimenters (me!).